# I wants to show the custom progress dialog (similar to iOS default dialog) in flutter

Tags: flutter

Currently I'm using the default flutter dialog

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFB50208),
          title: const Text('Progressbar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
    )
```

But below is the image what I need to implement

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to share what code you have already tried, and create a minal reproducible example so we can improve upon that. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [CupertinoActivityIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoActivityIndicator-class.html).

First import Cupertino Widgets :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

Then you can use this :

```dart
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
);
```

To dismiss, use `Navigator.pop(context);`.